# What happens if a thread doesn't succeed when making a pthread_mutex_lock() call?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I'm doing a experiment, which, I think, is a guaranteed deadlock situation:

```
void *thread_1(void *vptr)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&a);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&b);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&a);
}

void *thread_2(void *vptr)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&b);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&a);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&a);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&b);
}
```

What happens if a thread cannot lock? Does it get into a queue, waiting for the mutex, or does it simply move on to the next instruction?

Answer (score 1):

In your case both threads will be suspended forever waiting for the mutexes. If you start both threads at once.

Why don't you just create the mutexes and the threads and then run your example?

Answer (score 1):

If a thread tries to lock a mutex that is already locked by another thread, it will be suspended.  In this case, its execution will not continue until it has acquired the lock.  (There is no "queue" though - just an unordered set of waiting threads.  *Any* waiting thread could be the next to acquire the mutex).

If a thread tries to lock a mutex that is already locked by *itself* or not initialised properly, then `pthread_mutex_lock()` may return a non-zero error code, and execution will continue *without* the mutex being acquired.

Comment: Doing so is undefined behavior, so it could just as well result in `system("rm -rf /");`

Comment: @R.: It is my understanding that `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` are both in POSIX?

Comment: Recursive mutexes cannot return failure except for programming errors ([near-]infinite recursion). Error checking mutexes are essentially just a debugging tool. I would not call code that uses error checking mutexes and looks for an error to see if it already holds the lock to be good code, but I suppose it's at least valid.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the reason why it couldn't lock. E.g if the thread already holds the lock, an error might be returned.
You should check the return value, anyhow, and check the manual page for the error codes that are return in `errno`. Mine (linux) states:

> ```
>    The pthread_mutex_lock() function may fail if:
>
>    EDEADLK
>           The current thread already owns the mutex.
> ```

Comment: In correct code not operating on a process-shared mutex, `pthread_mutex_lock` can never return an error. The only errors it's allowed to return indicate *programming* errors, not exceptional conditions at runtime.

Comment: I should have said *robust* along with *process-shared*. Anyway the point of my comment was checking the return value of `pthread_mutex_lock` is not necessary (or useful) except when debugging or using process-shared robust mutexes (in which case you need to check for `EOWNERDEAD`).

Comment: *May*, not *shall*. Unless you have created an error-checking or recurive mutex, the behavior on attempting to lock a mutex you already hold a lock on is *undefined*, and therefore it's a programming error to do so.